# populating and accessing data from a value object

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, dictionary, value-objects, robotlegs

I have have a problem loading and accessing data from a value object in my new project.. I load an xml file via a service, which contains title and locations of asset files, I need to be able to access the location of an asset file by specifying the title and retrieiving it from a value object.. I'm using the Robotlegs framework, here's an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<files id ="xmlroot">
<file title="css_shell"                 location = "css/shell.css"  />
<file title="xml_shell"                 location = "xml/shell.xml"  />
<file title="test"                      location=   "test/location/test.jpg" />
<file title ="shell_background_image"   location = "images/shell_images/background_image.jpg" />
</files>
```

I then push this data into a value object as a Dictionary hash.. hopefully

```
//-----------  populate value objects ------------------------------------
var xml:XML = new XML(xml);
var files:XMLList = xml.files.file;

for each (var file:XML in files) {
var filePathVO:DataVO = new FilePathVO( file.@title.toString(),
     file.location.toString()
);

 filePathModel.locationList.push(filePathVO);
filePathModel.locationHash[filePathVO.title] = filePathVO;
 }
```

I've tested accessing this from a view component.

```
// accessing from another class -----------------

var _background_image_path:String = String( filePathModel.locationHash['shell_background_image']);
```

it returns undefined.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `@` for location attribute on this line:

```
var filePathVO:DataVO = new FilePathVO(file.@title.toString(),
     file.location.toString());
```

The real problem lies on the line:

```
var files:XMLList = xml.files.file;
```

Change it to

```
var files:XMLList = xml.file;
```

The `xml` variable refers to the root tag of the xml; there is no need to access it explicitly with `xml.files`. `xml.files.file` actually looks for `file` tags that are direct children of `files` tags that are direct children of the root-xml tag. It would've worked had your xml been something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <files id ="xmlroot">
    <file title="css_shell" location = "css/shell.css"  />
    <file title="xml_shell" location = "xml/shell.xml"  />
    <file title="test" location=   "test/location/test.jpg" />
    <file title ="shell_background_image" location = "images/shell_images/background_image.jpg" />
  </files>
</root>
```